# CoreData NSFetchedResultsController Sorting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a small problem with sorting my `NSFetchedResultsController`.

My `NSManagedObject` has two attributes. `date` and `startTime`.

The `date` is of time 00:00:00 on all my objects, this way when using `date` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` it grabs all the objects with identical dates (by day) into one section. If the time of the dates were different, it would put every object into a different section.

This works well, but then inside each group I want to sort the objects by `startTime`. So they are list from earliest on that `date` to the latest in each section respectively.

My issue is when using `date` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` and `startTime` as an NSSortDescriptor` it doesn't like it and plays weirdly. Such as only sometimes showing certain data in what seems like an irregular way.

I think it comes down to having to have the sort descriptor and `sectionNameKeyPath` the same. Am I right in thinking this? If not, how should I setup my `NSFetchedResultsController` to list my data in the fashion mentioned?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is come code... Also worth noting when using `startTime` as my second sort descriptor, it causes duplicates to display in my tableview with nil objects.

`NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:@"Master"];
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` just a snippet showing how I designate each managed object:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.flightFetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionFlights = [sectionInfo objects];
    Flight *flight = [sectionFlights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.flightFetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.flightFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: Show some code. Is `startTime` a string? (make it a date).

Comment: It is a date already, code incoming...

Comment: You are getting objects incorrectly. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your section key name path needs to match the **first** sort descriptor.

So you could do...

```
// sectionKeyNamePath = @"date".

NSSortDescriptor *dateSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *startTimeSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:YES];

frc.request.sortDescriptors = @[dateSD, startTimeSD];
```

If you do this then it will sort (and section) by date and then sort each section by startTime.

**From your code**

You are getting the fetched objects incorrectly.

To get an object you need to use...

```
Flight *flight = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

A fetched results controller knows about its sections and rows. You don't need to split it apart.

Comment: Interesting, but this causes some odd results. Such as nil duplicates in my tableview. I've added code to the OP.

Comment: I don't believe so, getting the `Flight` object as you suggest would only pull from the first section (first array of objects) from experience. So for each section in the table you need to get the corresponding section objects. I feel I may have resolved it though, a total project clean has done it. Thanks for the tip of matching the first sort descriptor though, something I did not know!

Comment: The index path points to the section and row. It's how it works. It's not that I believe how it works, that's just how it works. Glad you got it sorted though.

Comment: Yes, if your data set will be changing often (i.e. comments on a post, etc...) then you're best using nil for the cache name :)

Comment: @JoshKahane note that I'm using `objectAtIndexPath` not `objectAtIndex` there is a difference there.

Comment: Ah! That was stupid of me, thanks for pointing that out. I'd glazed over it a little too quickly! That and a nil chache name has resolved it completely! Thanks.